# C Linked list only contains first element...not sure what happens to rest

Tags: c, linked-list

I posted a question a few days ago about a linked list in C.  I thought everything was ok then the prof emails us saying that instead of this signature:

```
int insert_intlist( INTLIST* lst, int n); /* Inserts an int (n) into an intlist from the beginning*/
```

He accidentally meant:

```
int insert_intlist( INTLIST** lst, int n); /* Inserts an int (n) into an intlist from the beginning*/
```

I thought to myself cool now that I have a pointer to a pointer I can move the pointer outside of main and when I return to main I will still have my complete linked list.

He starts off with giving us this:

```
INTLIST* init_intlist( int n ) 
 {
    INTLIST *lst; //pointer to store node
    lst = (INTLIST *)malloc(sizeof(INTLIST)); //create enough memory for the node
    lst->datum = n; //set the value
    lst->next = NULL; //set the pointer
    return lst; //return the new list
}
```

Which is simply to initialize the list like so in main:

```
   if (lst==NULL)
                  lst = init_intlist(i);
               else
                  insert_intlist(lst, i);
```

lst is of type INTLIST* so its defined as INTLIST* lst.  So I read in some numbers from a text file like 1 3 4 9.
It is supposed to create a linked list from this...so the first number would go to init_intlist(1);  And that was defined above.  Then it grabs the next number 3 in this case and calls insert_intlist(lst, 3).  Well here is my insert_intlist and all I want to do is insert at the beginning of the list:

```
int insert_intlist(INTLIST** lst, int n )
 {
    INTLIST* lstTemp; //pointer to store temporary node to be added to linked list
    lstTemp = (INTLIST *)malloc(sizeof(INTLIST)); //create enough memory for the node
    lstTemp->datum = n; //assign the value

    //check if there is anything in the list,
    //there should be, but just in case
    if(*lst == NULL)
       {
          *lst=lstTemp;
          lstTemp->next=NULL;
       }
    else
       { 
          lstTemp->next = *lst; //attach new node to the front
          *lst = lstTemp; //incoming new node becomes the head of the list
       } 

    return 0; 
 }
```

So if the list contained 1 initially this function would simply create a new node and then make this temp node->next point to the head of the list (which I thought was lst) and then reassign the head of the list to this new temp node.

It all looks like it is running right but when I try to print my list to the screen it only prints the number 1.

Anyone have any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not so helpful, but have you considered strangling your professor? :)

Comment: I think you should be giving your professor a failing grade!

Comment: I agree he just sent out email to the entire class letting them know his .h file was incorrect for various functions...boy what a mess this is.  It looks like the professor hasn't even coded this.  Maybe he got this assignment from the nutty professor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being passed a pointer to a pointer.  You want to alter the pointer that is being pointed to, not the pointer to a pointer itself.  Does that make sense?

```
if(lst == NULL)
```

Here you're checking to see if you were passed a NULL pointer.  Good practice for error checking, but not for what you were doing right there.  If `lst` is NULL, then you don't even have a pointer to a pointer, can't do anything, and should return a nonzero error code without doing anything else.

Once you're sure your pointer is not NULL, *then* you look at the pointer it's pointing to (`*lst`).  The pointed-to pointer is the pointer to the first list item.  If *that* pointer is NULL, *then* you change it to the new item's pointer.  Basically, where you use `lst` you should be using `*lst` or `(*lst)`.  (REMEMBER: the `*` operator runs *after* the `->` operator!  So to get a field in the object pointed to by the pointer that is pointed to by `lst` [pant, pant], you use `(*lst)->whatever`.)

P.S. This kind of pointer work is *critical* to learn to be a good programmer, especially with C.

P.P.S. The other thing you got wrong is that instead of

```
insert_intlist(lst, i);
```

you're supposed to call it like

```
insert_intlist(&lst, i);
```

... and, for brownie points, check the return code for errors.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why &lst I know & is the address of...but seriously this class is just really difficult, this was our FIRST ASSIGNMENT and I have had to learn C basically on my own.

Comment: `&lst` because what you are passing is the pointer to a pointer to the list while `lst` is only a pointer to a list. Note that "pointer to" is synonymous with "address of".

Comment: Can anyone recommend a good book, this stuff is really difficult I cant believe I am getting this far....

Comment: *The C Programming Language*?  Though I don't know how good its stuff on data structures is, if any.  You could also search for "C data structures" or "C linked lists" on Google and see what comes up.  For the record, this is where a data structures class needs to start.  You have to get this kind of singly-linked list down pat before you go on to doubly-linked lists, binary trees, queues, sparse arrays, and other structures.

Comment: P.S. *The C Programming Language* is by Kernighan and Ritchie, the guys who wrote the language; ISBN 978-0131103627.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that pops into my mind is that in `insert_intlist()` you're doing `lst = lstTemp;`. This should be `*lst = lstTemp;`. This way you assign to the list pointer that you were supplied rather than to the list pointer pointer (which does not update anything outside of the function).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a pointer to another pointer in the insert function, you can change at which memory location the latter *actually* points to. I changed the insert code a bit and it works fine:

```
int insert_intlist(INTLIST** lst, int n )
{
    INTLIST* lstTemp; //pointer to store temporary node to be added to linked list
    lstTemp = (INTLIST *)malloc(sizeof(INTLIST)); //create enough memory for the node
    lstTemp->datum = n; //assign the value

    //check if there is anything in the list,
    //there should be, but just in case
    if(*lst == NULL)
    {
      lstTemp->next=NULL;
      *lst = lstTemp;
    }
    else
    { 
      lstTemp->next = *lst; //attach new node to the front
      *lst = lstTemp; //incoming new node becomes the head of the list
    } 

return 0;
```

}

EDIT: I see you edited your question. In that case, maybe you are calling the insert function in the wrong way in main(). Try this

```
int main()
{
    INTLIST *head;
    head = init_intlist(42);
    insert_intlist(&head, 41);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have the same thing but iin main when I try to print the list it only displays one element.

Comment: how are you printing the list?

Comment: If it helps, I posted the whole code here: http://dpaste.de/ZDKt/
I can verify it works fine for me. Maybe something wrong with the function you use to traverse the linked list?

Comment: Ok I had called it the wrong way...can you explain why &lst rather then just lst???

Comment: jimh86, see the very first line I posted. lst is a pointer to a INTLIST type. The insert function requires a double pointer. A pointer is a variable, just like any other. So you pass on the address of the lst pointer with the & operator.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if lstTemp->next == NULL after lstTemp->next=lst;